# Export iptables logs to network storage in a limited storage dd-wrt router

Tags: security, iptables, firewall, router

Because some routers have very limited storage space; security logs are disabled in the micro version of **dd-wrt**. Is it possible to export the (*iptables*) logs to an external storage?

Comment: Why don't you just log to a remote syslog server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can log to a remote syslog daemon.  The default program will truncate long messages.
If you have memory your can use syslog-ng.  Installation should be similar to my installation of S[yslog-ng on openWrt](http://www.systemajik.com/blog/openwrt-syslog-ng-installation/).

Comment: I can't install anything on the router it's 2Mb flash only.

Comment: In that case, you should be able to specify the IP address of a server running a syslog daemon.  You will need to configure it to listen for network messages.  Then configure the router to log to that IP address.